# Read Staggerd List into MultiDimensional Array

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, text-files

I have a staggered list saved as a text file, and I need to read that file into a multi dimensional array, where the header is in the first level, and all lines under it are the second level.

EX:

```
Greetings
    Hello
    How are you
    Have a great day
Needs
    Help
    I need a drink
```

Array(0,0) = Greetings

Array(0,1) = Hello

Array(0,2) = How are you

How can I loop through this information and know when it reaches the second column?

Comment: I'm guessing `Array(1,0) = Needs`?

Comment: Probably when the line read `StartsWith("    ")`  (or maybe when `LineRead <> LineRead.Trim`) but since this looks like a lookup table, a DIctionary or List might be a better container

Comment: How would I put it into a list, with the same subcategories?

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to do.  Is this going to be used for some sort of look up?  A user types `Hello` and you present the set of items assigned to that entry (or vice versa)?

Comment: Yes, Something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to uses lists rather than arrays for this. However, the following code will create a ragged array that represents your categories.

```
Dim lists As New List(Of String())
Dim currentGroup As New List(Of String)
For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    If line.StartsWith(" ") Then
        currentGroup.Add(line.Trim)
    Else
        If currentGroup.Count > 0 Then lists.Add(currentGroup.ToArray)
        currentGroup = New List(Of String) From {line}
    End If
Next
If currentGroup.Count > 0 Then lists.Add(currentGroup.ToArray)
Dim myArray()() As String = lists.ToArray
```

Comment: This worked however the last group is not added to the lists because it reached the end of the file. If there are items in the current group, you need to add them after the file is finished

Comment: @Dmandy I edited the answer to correct that (adding the next to last statement). I think you must have used the origin version of the code.